# Add autoplay function to simple jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sliders

My current slider functions perfect, and also has a working pagination (paginated dots, active state, and control) but I just want to add **ONE new feature without breaking anything**:

**The ability for my slider to autoplay on page load.**

Any suggestions, greatly appreciated.

**HTML / Markup:**

```
<div class="allslideshow">
    <div class="slideshow-wrapper">
        <div class="slide" id="s1"></div>
        <div class="slide" id="s2"></div>
        <div class="slide" id="s3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-nav"> <a href="#s1">•</a>
 <a href="#s2">•</a>
 <a href="#s3">•</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var Slideshow = {
    paginate: function () {
        var slides = $('div.slide', '.allslideshow'),
            total = slides.length;
        $('.slideshow-nav-total').text(total);
        slides.each(function (i) {
            $(this).data('index', i + 1);
        });
    },
    navigate: function () {
        $('a', '.slideshow-nav').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $a = $(this);
            var slide = $($a.attr('href'));
            var wrapper = $('.slideshow-wrapper');
            wrapper.animate({
                left: -slide.position().left
            }, 500, 'linear', function () {
                $('.slideshow-nav-current').text(slide.data('index'));
                $a.addClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');
            });

        });
    },
    init: function () {
        this.paginate();
        this.navigate();
    }
};
$(function () {
    Slideshow.init();
    });
});
```

**Attempt:**

```
// autoplay: function () {
//      .ready(function) { 
//         e.preventDefault();
//         var $a = $(this);
//         var slide = $($a.attr('href'));
//         var wrapper = $('.slideshow-wrapper');
//         wrapper.animate({
//             left: -slide.position().left
//         }, 300, 'linear', function () {
//             $('.slideshow-nav-current').text(slide.data('index'));
//             $a.addClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');
//          });

//     });
// },
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML? I'm trying to figure out how to match your original result in Plunker.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Took longer than I thought, the plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GDtAoO5zmkd8u2Di8Gjs?p=preview), and I'll start writing up an answer. It doesn't look like anything since I decided not to guess the CSS for your slider. I'm just watching the "Current" readout.

Comment: @AustinMullins excited to see the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to move forward is to abstract away the animation function from the "click" event handler on your links. That way you can call the animation function from both a click and a timer event. The tricky thing about this is that you have to capture the `this` context in order to use it inside a closure. Here's what I mean:

```
//...
moveTo: function($a) {
  var slide = $($a.attr('href'));
  var wrapper = $('.slideshow-wrapper');
  wrapper.animate({
    left: -slide.position().left
  }, 500, 'linear', function () {
    $('.slideshow-nav-current').text(slide.data('index'));
    $a.addClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');
  });
},
navigate: function () {
    var self = this;
    $('a', '.slideshow-nav').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (self.interval) {
          clearInterval(self.interval);
          self.interval = false;
        }
        var $a = $(this);
        self.moveTo($a);
    });
},
autoPlay: function() {
  var $alist = $('a', '.slideshow-nav');
  var i = 0;
  var self = this;
  this.interval = setInterval(function() {
    var $a = $alist.eq(i++);
    i %= $alist.length;
    self.moveTo($a);
  }, 1000);
},
init: function () {
    this.paginate();
    this.navigate();
    this.autoPlay();
}
//...
```

[Try it in a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GDtAoO5zmkd8u2Di8Gjs?p=preview).

Comment: // Thanks so much! The only problem with this.. is the pagination stops working after it looks one time! Any suggestions!?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that cycling through the links (using the line `i %= $alist.length`) isn't working for you?

Comment: No, the pagination dots stop working once it cycles through one time.

Comment: That's interesting. Can you post what you're seeing on a Plunker or other host?

Comment: I guess you got it to work? What needed to be fixed to make the pagination dots work?

Comment: This was kind of the overall problem:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282210/reset-slideshows-to-start-at-first-slide-with-each-clickhandler-button

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a timeout that will automatically call the function that changes images So it would be something like

```
              setInterval(function(){
                    //call the function here
                }, 6000);
```

Comment: Makes sense! So, in my case I should just wrap it around starting at e.prevent?

Comment: So one thing to keep in mind is that if you wrap it around start/end, the initializer would be called after a certain time which is bad. So what I would suggest is either keeping the initilizer out or assigning names to your functions such as loadImage so you can just call loadImage() outside to initilize and inside the setInterval to automatically change

Answer (score 1):

SetIntervl will cause a delayed intialization.Just call your initializer function on window load like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
 //call the init function here
}
```

Comment: Set Interval will cause a delay if you wrap the whole code inside it, if have a global call to the initilizing function it wont be a problem. And how does this create an autoplay?